# How to attach an image to a post using wordpress and xml-rpc?

Tags: php, wordpress, xml-rpc

I'd like to create a new post with an attached image on a remote Wordpress blog, using xml-rpc. I **can't** afford to edit any Wordpress core files. I'm using IXR_Client, which I found in Wordpress/wp-includes/ .

I am able to upload the image (metaWeblog.newMediaObject) and create the post (metaWeblog.newPost).

I can't figure out how to link them.

I could overwrite the post's custom fields, but for this I need to find the attachment_id.

Any advices ?
Thank you very much.